# Terraform TF file error: An argument named "XYZ" is not expected here. Did you mean to define a block of type "XYZ"?

Tags: terraform, terraform-template-file, terraform-provider

I am trying to create Provider in Terraform. I have requirement to store array of structure.

TF File Detail (sample detail):

```
resource "sample_ldu" "myldu" {
  // multiple variables ...
   ldus = [
        {
          ld = 11
          lu = 12
        },
      ]
}
```

Here i need array of ld-lu, so i can add multiple ld, lu.

My Provider Schema (for sample):

```
"ldus": &schema.Schema{
        Type:     schema.TypeList,
        Optional: true,
        Elem: &schema.Resource{
            Schema: map[string]*schema.Schema{
                "ld": {
                    Optional: true,
                    Type:     schema.TypeInt,
                },
                "lu": {
                    Optional: true,
                    Type:     schema.TypeInt,
                },
            },
        },
    },
```

Terraform Version: Terraform v1.3.9

Terraform Init - OK

Terraform Plan - Giving Error

```
Error: Unsupported argument
│ 
│   on ldu_create.tf line 30, in resource "sample_ldu" "myldu":
│   30:   ldus = [
│ 
│ An argument named " ldus" is not expected here. Did you mean to define a
│ block of type " ldus"?
```

Simple int_value = 10, array_value =[ 10, 20]  etc are working fine.
But if I am adding array of integer structure then it is giving error.

Can you please help me how I can achieve this scenario in Terraform TF file for my provider?

Is it possible to add this type of structure in TF files?

```
ldus = [
        {
          ld = 11
          lu = 12
        },
     ]
```

Comment: This looks like SDKv2 and not the plugin framework. I have an open issue at the moment for doing this in the plugin framework because it should theoretically be possible, but it appears this may just not be possible in SDKv2 schema based on your question.

Comment: yes, right. not able to achieve in SDKv2

Comment: I have confirmed this is possible in the plugin framework, and have implemented it for a provider. If you migrate then that would also solve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not found solution for this structure.

But adding multiple in List is solve my problem for now.

```
    lud{
        ld = 11
        lu = 12
    }
    lud{
        ld = 13
        lu = 14
    }
```